# Добавление элементов в TabPage (null refference exception)

Tags: c#

Пытаюсь создать табы с внутренними листбоксами.

```
for (int i = tv.TabCount + 1; i <= newcount; i++)
                    {
                        tv.TabPages.Add("таб " + i);

                        tv.TabPages[i - 1].Container.Add(new ListBox());
                    }
```

Если создание самого таба проходит, то добавление в него листбокса нет, вываливается nullreference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вместо

```
tv.TabPages[i - 1].Container.Add(new ListBox());
```

надо

```
tv.TabPages[i - 1].Controls.Add(new ListBox());
```

Comment: спасибо, проглядел ошибку